# Why does concurrent.futures return an empty file when appending the results to a list?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use `concurrent.futures` to read several `.json` files and store the results in a list. below is my code:

```
data = []
PATH_TO_JSON = '/media/My Passport/echo2_1'

def jsonread (file):
    path = PATH_TO_JSON + '/' + file
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line.rstrip('\n|\r')))


with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    files = [file for file in listdir(PATH_TO_JSON)]
    results = executor.map(jsonread, files)
```

but the code returns an empty `data` list. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018676/multiprocessing-using-concurrent-futures-appending-list). But I cannot apply the answer to my work. I appreciate a detailed answer, as I am a newbie in `multiprocessing` and `concurrent.futures`.

Comment: First I would check each line is a well formed json. Print out  each line or catch the possible exception from `json.loads`. Second: how many files are there?

Comment: I have checked that and they are good. I just did not include the checks for concision. there are 15 ```.json``` files

Comment: Also, why using `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`? See the difference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Answer (score 0):

Each of the processes will start with their own memory. This makes it difficult to share data in a global list. Instead try refactoring the `jsonread` method to instead return a list.

```
def jsonread(file):
    data = []
    path = PATH_TO_JSON + '/' + file
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line.rstrip('\n|\r')))
    return data
```

For multi-process code you must make sure that the Python interpreter can import the main module without side-effects. Each process will launch an interpreter which will load the main module, so you must make sure that only the main process (the first interpreter) launches the `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Refactor your code to include a main guard around the `with` statement:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        files = [file for file in listdir(PATH_TO_JSON)]
        results = executor.map(jsonread, files)
```

If we are to print the value of `results` at the end we get:

```
print(results)
<generator object _chain_from_iterable_of_lists at 0x000001B45FD4A200>
```

What you see here is that we have a generator. Generators in python are lazy, they don't do anything until you call `next` on them. Because we changed `jsonread` to return a list of strings we will also have to join them together. Looping over the values in `jsonread` will implicitly invoke `next` on the generator. Final code:

```
PATH_TO_JSON = '/media/My Passport/echo2_1'


def jsonread(file):
    data = []
    path = PATH_TO_JSON + '/' + file
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line.rstrip('\n|\r')))
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        files = [file for file in listdir(PATH_TO_JSON)]
        results = executor.map(jsonread, files)
        data = [line for result in results for line in result]
```

Comment: Is the last line ```data = [line for result in results for line in result]``` true?